# how to download file from git project folder to jenkins server

Tags: selenium, jenkins, github

I have a git repository where my selenium project is kept. Jenkins pick this project runs the mentioned test cases. 
One of the test cases have file upload code. This code fails because the VM machine on which jenkins runs the code does have these files . We do not have access to this VM machine.
Is there a way to download the file from git project folder in jenkins server and then try to upload this file on the application.
I tried opening the file on git and then clicked on RAW , right clicked on the page and clicked on save as but it is opening the windows interaction of my local machine.

Please help.

Comment: Check <kbd>file_detector</kbd> option in selenium [here](https://saucelabs.com/blog/selenium-tips-uploading-files-in-remote-webdriver)

Comment: @supputuri , that is for how to upload the file. i want to know to download a file from git project folder to jenkins server.

Comment: You can use Pastebin/[File.io](https://File.io) where you can upload the file that's been downloaded in the machine where browser is running and download the same whereever you need the file for validation.

Comment: Please share the selenim language bindings info that you are using.

Comment: @supputuri , I am using java language in selenium

Comment: Jenkins had clone your project code to slave where your test cod running.  Why those files for testing uploading not  in the slave?